# Is it possible to have a minor mode re-evaluate its keymap?

Tags: keymap, minor-mode

My code:

```lisp
;;; foo.el --- Example minor mode

;; Mode developer code.
(defvar hello-key (kbd "C-c C-f"))

(defun print-hello ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Hello!"))

(defun make-my-keymap ()
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map hello-key 'print-hello)
    map))

(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Foo mode"
  :lighter " Foo"
  :keymap (make-my-keymap)
  (when foo-mode
    (setq foo-mode-map (make-my-keymap))))

(defun foo-mode-turn-on ()
  (foo-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-foo-mode foo-mode foo-mode-turn-on)

;; User code.
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq hello-key (kbd "C-c C-j"))
(global-foo-mode 1)
```

I have split the code above into 2 parts. The first part contains the code for the minor mode. The bottom three lines show how the user may use the mode.

The user wants to set the `hello-key` to `(kbd "C-c C-j")` before enabling the mode. But the minor mode ignores this new value of `hello-key` because it has already used the old value `(kbd "C-c C-f")` while defining the keymap for the minor mode.

Is it possible to create a minor mode in a way that every time the user enables the minor mode, the minor mode re-evaluates its keymap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Minor Mode Keymaps

The problem with the current code in the question is that it merely updates the variable `foo-mode-map` but it does not really update the keymap data structure made of cons cells that defines the keymap for the minor mode. That data structure (the mode's keymap) is cached in the variable `minor-mode-map-alist`, so it is necessary to look up the keymap for `foo-mode` in that alist and update that.

For example, after executing the question, if we enter `C-h v foo-mode-map RET` and `C-h v minor-mode-map-alist RET`, then we will find that `foo-mode-map` has been updated to the following:

```lisp
(keymap (3 keymap (10 . print-hello)))
```

However the variable `minor-mode-map-alist` still has the old keymap as shown below:

```
((foo-mode keymap (3 keymap (6 . print-hello)))
 (context-menu-mode keymap ...)
 ...)
```

Therefore we need to look up the cons cell with `'foo-mode` in `minor-mode-map-alist` and then set its `cdr` to the re-evaluated keymap. The following section shows how.

#### Solution

```lisp
(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Foo mode"
  :lighter " Foo"
  :keymap (make-my-keymap)
  (when foo-mode
    (setcdr (assq 'foo-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
            (make-my-keymap))))
```

But beware that this is not a common pattern for setting keymaps for minor modes. The problem with this approach is that if the user modifies the mode's keymap to add their own key bindings, they will be lost when then mode is disabled and enabled again.

#### Complete Code

Here is the complete solution shown together at one place for convenience:

```lisp
;;; foo.el --- Example minor mode

;; Mode developer code.
(defvar hello-key (kbd "C-c C-f"))

(defun print-hello ()
  (interactive)
  (message "Hello!"))

(defun make-my-keymap ()
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map hello-key 'print-hello)
    map))

(define-minor-mode foo-mode
  "Foo mode"
  :lighter " Foo"
  :keymap (make-my-keymap)
  (when foo-mode
    (setcdr (assq 'foo-mode minor-mode-map-alist)
            (make-my-keymap))))

(defun foo-mode-turn-on ()
  (foo-mode 1))

(define-globalized-minor-mode global-foo-mode foo-mode foo-mode-turn-on)

;; User code.
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
(setq hello-key (kbd "C-c C-j"))
(global-foo-mode 1)
```